# Help translating a medical phrase

Tags: translation

Could you please help me translate this phrase?

대향2문접선조사?

It has to do with radiation therapy. I found 접선조사 means tangential radiation, and 대향 means opposed. But, I'm not sure about the 2문 part.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a medical professional.  I googled around until i found [this article](http://update.odis.co.kr/ArgosCMS2/Search/PopUpAbstract.do?cno=519607).

[image]
[image]

The screenshot of the page is for longevity of this solution.

from this post, i can concur that `대향 2문 접선조사` translates to

> Opposing Portal Irradiation

**The `2문` (two doors) combines with `대향` (as you suspected) to produce `opposing portals`.**

[Perhaps the article will shed more light.  From my non-medical background, it is hard to tell, but my instincts tell me the translation is very good.](http://update.odis.co.kr/ArgosCMS2/Search/PopUpAbstract.do?cno=519607)

Comment: Thank you very much! I also tried to google it, but wasn't as successful as you. I tried to upvote your comment but don't have enough reputation yet. Thank you again!